# Spark for Kubernetes Test on Mac

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

Trying to build the image from the provided download. Used "Source Code" package option download, not Hadoop versions.  Following spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/running-on-kubernetes.html#docker-images first step to build a docker image. Have Docker CE with K8s running on Mac.

Using Terminal: Ran in spark folder:

```
./bin/docker-image-tool.sh -r cloud.docker.com/xxxx/spark build
```

All runs until here:

> Step 5/14 : COPY ${spark_jars} /opt/spark/jars
>   COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder840552377/assembly/target/scala-2.12/jars: no such file or directory

Please assist a newbie!  Not sure where this folder structure is or whats up.
Please don't assume I did something correct....I could have missed an obvious install before running this. Help is appreciated after you laugh. :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've cloned the right [spark](https://github.com/apache/spark.git) project and then Build spark with this command

```
./build/mvn -Pkubernetes -DskipTests clean package
```

If you just need to solve your current error, use this command (-pl is used to build a specified module where spark-assembly_2.11 is the artifactId as defined in assembly/pom.xml file.)

```
build/mvn -pl :spark-assembly_2.11 clean install
```

The scala jar will be available in the Assembly module folder.